# 400 Bad request - API call - using React {this.state.input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, routes

I'm building an app which the user uploads a food picture and the API will respond with the ingredients. on my onButtonSubmit, if I write an url to test, it works. But if I use {this.state.input} it sends me the 400 Bad Request.

Might be related with my FoodRecognition.JS (separate file). If write

Could someone help me please? Code below.

Thanks in advance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Clarifai from 'clarifai'
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation'
import FoodRecognition from './components/Food_recognition/Food_recognition'
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo'
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm'
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin'
import Register from './components/Register/Register'
import './App.css'

const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '6382df74e5c243f589fff9057a7e41bd'
 });


class App extends Component {
  constructor()  {
    super()
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({imput: event.target.value})

  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
    app.models
    .predict( 
      Clarifai.FOOD_MODEL,
      this.state.input)
      .then(
    function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    },
    function(err) {
    }
  );
  }

onRouteChange = (route) => {
  if (route === 'signout') {
    this.setState({isSignedIn: false})
  } else if (route === 'home') {
    this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
  }
this.setState({route: route})
}

  render() { 
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn}onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        {route === 'home'
          ? <div>
            <Logo />
            <ImageLinkForm
              onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
              onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit} />
            <FoodRecognition imageUrl={imageUrl} />
          </div>
          : (
            route === 'signin'
              ? <Signin onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
              : <Register onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**FoodRecognition.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const FoodRecognition = ({ imageUrl }) => {
    return (
    <div className='center ma'>
    <div className='absolute mt2'>
        <img alt='' src={imageUrl} width='500px' height='auto'/>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default FoodRecognition
```

Comment: you might have a typo in `onInputChange` in `this.setState({imput: event.target.value})`, it should be `input`. Can you please try after correcting it? If it doesn't work, let me know, will dig into your question a bit more.

Comment: It was. Thanks a lot for your time @dubes!

Comment: Cool! I am going to vote to close this question, as it was just a typo. Don't worry, it is nothing against you, this just makes it easier to remove false matches when people search for problems

Comment: No worries thanks. It was my first stackoverflow question. How can I close it?

Comment: Don't worry, I have flagged it for moderators to close. Btw, Welcome to SO! Your question was actually very well put for someone new to the site, the code samples also helped me spot the issue right away! Usually I've to point people to our guides.